# C - clarifying delimiters in strtok

Tags: c, delimiter, strtok

I'm trying to break up a shell command that contains both pipes (|) and the OR symbols (||) represented as characters in an array with strtok, except, well the OR command could also be two pipes next to each other. Specifically, I need to know when |, ;, &&, or || show up in the command.

Is there a way to specify where one delimiter ends and another begins in strtok, since I know usually the delimiters are one character long and you just list them all out with no spaces or anything in between.

Oh and, is a newline a valid delimiter? Or does strtok only do spaces?

Comment: You may want to consider using a real [lexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) like [flex](http://flex.sourceforge.net/). There's a bit of a learning curve, but once you learn how to use it, you can create lexical analyzers easily -- even complicated ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your purpose, `strtok()` is not the correct tool to use; it destroys the delimiter, so you can't tell what was at the end of a token if someone types `ls|wc`.  It could have been a pipe, a semi-colon, and ampersand, or a space.  Also, it treats multiple adjacent delimiters as part of a single delimiter.

Look at `strspn()` and `strcspn()`; both are in standard C and are non-destructive relatives of `strtok()`.

`strtok()` is quite happy to use newline as a delimiter; in fact, any character except `'\0'` can be used as one of the delimiters.

There are other reasons for being extremely cautious about using `strtok()`, such as thread safety and the fact that it is highly unwise to use it in library code.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from your last question: yes, `strtok` can use new-line as a delimiter without any problems.

Unfortunately, the answer to your first question isn't nearly so positive. `strtok` treats all delimiter characters as equal, and does nothing to differentiate between a single delimiter and an arbitrary number of consecutive delimiters. In other words, if you give `|&;` as the delimiter, it'll treat `|||||||||` or `&&&` or `&|&|;` all exactly the same way.

I'll go a little further: I'll go out on a limb and state as a fact that `strtok` simply isn't suitable for breaking a shell command into constituent pieces -- I'm pretty sure there's just no way to use it for this job that will produce usable results.

In particular, you don't have anything that *just* acts as a delimiter. For your purposes, the `&`, `|`, and `||` are tokens of their own. In a string being supplied to the shell, you don't necessarily have *anything* that qualifies as a delimiter the way `strtok` "thinks" of them.

`strtok` is oriented toward tokens that are separated by delimiters that are *nothing* except delimiters. As `strtok` reads the tokens, the delimiters between them are completely ignored (and, destroyed, for that matter). For the shell, a string like `a|b` is really three tokens -- you need the `a`, the `|` and the `b` -- there's nothing between them that `strtok` can safely overwrite and/or ignore -- but that's a requirement for how `strtok` works. For it to deliver you the first `a`, it overwrites the next character (the `|` in this case) with a `'\0'`. Then it has no way of recovering that pipe to tell you what the next token should be.

I think you probably need a greedy tokenizer instead -- i.e., one that builds the longest string of characters that can be token, and stops when it encounters a character that can't be part of the current token. When you ask for the next token, it starts from the first character after the end of the previous token, without (necessarily) skipping/ignoring anything (though, of course, if it encounters something like white-space that hasn't been quoted somehow, it'll probably skip over it).

Answer (score 1):

`strtok()` is a basic, all-purpose parsing function. For more advanced parsing, I don't recommend its use.

For example, in the case of '|', you really need to inspect the next character to determine if you've found '|' or '||'.

I've done a huge amount of parsing of this nature, including writing a small language interpreter. It's not that hard if you break it up into smaller tasks. But my advice is to write your own parsing routine in this case.

And, yes, a newline character is a valid delimiter.